# Schedule SMS for later date with Twilio + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I want to send a SMS either now or at a specific time using Twilio + Rails, but am unsure of best practices approach. I don't think cron is appropriate for this.

I have a simple view-

```
<div>
  <%= form_for @text_message, url: {action: "send_message"}, 
  html: {role: "form", class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|%>
    <%= f.text_field :from  %>
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'text-input' %>
    <div class="schedule-outer">
      <a id="schedule-link">
        <span>Schedule text for later?</span>
       </a>
    </div>   
    <div >
      <%= f.datetime_select :scheduled_date, ampm: true, minute_step: 15, value: nil %> <br>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Send Text Message"%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the corresponding controller-

```
class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @text_message = TextMessage.new
  end

  def send_message
    number_to_send_to = params[:text_message][:to]
    number_sent_from = params[:text_message][:from]
    the_payload = params[:text_message][:body]

    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH'])


    @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
     from: "#{number_sent_from}",
     to: "#{number_to_send_to}",
     body: "#{the_payload}"
    )

    flash[:notice] = "Your text has been sent!"
    redirect_to action: 'new'
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get 'text_messages/new', to: "text_messages#new"
post '/send_message' => "text_messages#send_message"
```

textmessage.rb

```
class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :from, :to, :scheduled_date

end
```

Right now, if you fill out the form it sends the sms to whatever parameters you input. I'm having trouble design-wise for a next step.

Here are my thoughts

- A `before_filter` in the controller to check if the `:scheduled_date` is nil or not.
- if it is nil send it immediately if not send it to a scheduler(?)

Problems

- This actually doesn't seem to create a text message object, it just sends the sms
- I'm not sure what an elegant next step might be.

Goal

- To allow someone to send a text message immediately or send it at a specified time in the form

Question

- What is a good next step to implement this?

#### **Updated**

Here is my updated controller/form code based on scheduler advice, I expect this as my solution moving forward.

```
class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @text_message = TextMessage.new
  end

  def send_message
    number_to_send_to = params[:text_message][:to]
    number_sent_from = params[:text_message][:from]
    the_payload = params[:text_message][:body]
    @text_message = TextMessage.create(params[:text_message])
    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH'])

    if @text_message.scheduled_date == nil
      @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
       from: "#{number_sent_from}",
       to: "#{number_to_send_to}",
       body: "#{the_payload}"
      )
    else
      # add it to a scheduler
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Your text has been sent!"
    redirect_to action: 'new'
  end
end
```

form

```
  <%= f.datetime_select :scheduled_date, ampm: true, minute_step: 15, include_blank: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid having different logic for messages to be sent now or in the future. If you don't need any part of the response (currently you don't do anything with it) then the easiest thing is to move it to the background in any case. Big advantage is that the response time and availability of the service has no impact on the response time of your site.

A good tool for queueing jobs in the background is resque (https://github.com/resque/resque) which can be extended with resque-scheduler (https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) to allow having jobs done at some point in the future (instead of just Resque.enqueue you would then use Resque.enqueue_in and/or Resque.enqueue_at to move tasks to the queue).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation I'm currently going with, I'm sure it can be improved.

I added [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.io/sidekiq/) and [redis](http://redis.io/) for background job processing. Here is my twilio worker

```
class TwilioWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(text_message_id)
    text_message = TextMessage.find(text_message_id)
    number_to_send_to = text_message.to
    number_sent_from =  text_message.from
    the_payload = text_message.body
    @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(ENV['TWILIO_SID'], ENV['TWILIO_AUTH'])

    @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
     from: "#{number_sent_from}",
     to: "#{number_to_send_to}",
     body: "#{the_payload}"
    )
  end
end
```

Here is my updated `text_messages_controller.rb`

```
class TextMessagesController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @text_message = TextMessage.new
  end

  def send_message
    @text_message = TextMessage.new(params[:text_message])

    if @text_message.save
      if @text_message.scheduled_date == nil
        TwilioWorker.perform_async(@text_message.id)
      elsif @text_message.scheduled_date != nil 
        time = ((@text_message.scheduled_date - @text_message.created_at) / 3600).round
        TwilioWorker.perform_at(time.hours, @text_message.id)

      else
        flash[:notice] = "something went wrong"
      end

    else
      redirect_to action: 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

rbates [sidekiq railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) was great for setting this up.